# Requestign addional permission to linkedin via ProviderSigninController

Tags: spring, spring-social

I'm using spring social to login using linked-in, I need to request for additional permission, I do with scope variable for other providers (facebook, twitter) it just works fine but for linked-in it does not, since Linked-in uses oAuth 1.0 it's not supported - is what I could see in other forums, I'm sure there is a work around could you suggest one ?

```
<form id="linkedin-login" action="signin/linkedin" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="r_fullprofile"  />
</form>
```

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I'm answering back to my own question, that might be some help to others as well.

Linkedin uses OAuth 1.0a. OAuth1.0 officially does not support scoping of authorization, It's only Linkedin extension to OAuth1.0, since Spring social follows the standard of OAuth1.0, the scoping does not come out of the box, it needs a work around of overriding / adding new ProviderSigninController, connect controller and Connectsupport (getAccessToken method) classes.

More details: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?129684-Linked-In-member-permissions